# Automated aab upload form GitHub to Google Playstore failing with cryptic message (Invalid value track_config)

Tags: github-actions, google-play-console, android-app-bundle

I am trying to automatically upload the aab file of my app to Google Play Store internal (test channel) from GitHub. The process is automated and worked a week ago. Now the GitHub upload step fails with message

```
Adding 1 artifacts to release on 'internal' track
Error: Invalid value at 'track_config.releases[0].status' (type.googleapis.com/google.play.publishingapi.v3.Release.Status), ""
```

Googling for this message, I found the hint the app ID could differ but they are same in play store and in aab.

Version code in aab is properly incremented (66 in store, 69 in aab).

Does anybody have an idea what else could be wrong here or how to get more details about the error?

EDIT: The GitHub step I am running is as follows

```
  - name: Upload Deployable to Play Store
    uses: r0adkll/upload-google-play@v1
    with:
      track: internal
      serviceAccountJsonPlainText: ${{ secrets.ANDROID_PLAYSTORE_ACCOUNT_KEY }}
      packageName: de.ilapark.charge.pp
      releaseFiles: build/app/outputs/bundle/release/*.aab
      whatsNewDirectory: dist/whatsnew
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

explicitly setting status to draft solved this issue for me.

[the README for upload-google-play](https://github.com/r0adkll/upload-google-play) lists a couple of values that might be better suited for your use case then draft

Comment: Great, this solved it. seems Google added some kind of validation here between my uploads.

Comment: Note: I am now using
 status: completed
which the Play Store also accepts. "complete" automatically causes Google to publish the new version whereas "draft" requires me to publish it manually at the Google console.

Answer (score 0):

Track names in request path and request body must match.

Just add to the Track object (the "body") the string value of TrackValue and it will work : `TrackValue = track,`

```
    var updatedTrack = this.Service.Edits.Tracks.Update(
    new Track()
    {
        TrackValue = track,
        Releases = new List<TrackRelease>
        {                
            new TrackRelease
            {
    Name = versionName,
    VersionCodes = apkVersionCodes,
    Status = "completed",
    ReleaseNotes = new List<LocalizedText>() { note }
            }
        }
    },
    packageName,
    edit.Id,
    track);
```

Comment: Hi Jabbar, thanks for trying to help but I am having difficulties to match your example to my own code. I added the GitHub workflow snippet to give more info about my problem to the original post.

Comment: I am not familiar with Github automated release. but please try this  `track: track`

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
track: internal
status: draft
```